# Response Header Propagation using HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient

There is a request header propagation feature in Asp.net core that we could propagate any header we receive onto another HTTP service.

Is there any feature(framework support) that we could use to propagate the received headers to caller service?

Do we have to access received headers and put in the response message manually?

Comment: I agree with @CodeCaster. Moreover, why would anyone want to do that? I fail to see a practical use case for such a thing.

Comment: Well there is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.headerpropagationservicecollectionextensions.addheaderpropagation?view=aspnetcore-7.0, but that links ASP.NET Core to a specific (named) HttpClient for a specific BaseAddress, for example. Can you tell what specifically you are looking for, apart from this being a dubious idea?

Answer (score 2):

The [header propagation feature](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.HeaderPropagation) [(GitHub PR introducing it](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/7921), [Learn mention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#header-propagation-middleware)), which is barely documented, is meant to propagate, from an ASP.NET Core viewpoint, *incoming* request headers to *outgoing* HTTP requests.

It won't add headers from responses received for outgoing HTTP requests made from your code to the response going to the browser.

Its intended use cases appears to be something like:

- A/B testing, feature flags (browser sends `Test-Feature: enable`, upstream service receives this with a one-time config)
- Language selection (`Accept-Language`)
- And other stuff set by client applications (browsers) where the ASP.NET Core application acts as a proxy or middleware, forwarding the specific headers to upstream services.

Not the other way around.

> Do we have to access received headers and put in the response message manually?

So, yes.

Comment: "Barely documented" is right ...